# pcl 1.72 installation question

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My source directory contains my testPCD.cpp program and PCL directory with pcl 1.7.2 called pcl-pcl-1.7.2. This was unziped here from tar file from pclcloud home page for 1.7.2 source.  I will download and compile ros dependent source as needed but first I need to get catkin_make to find 1.7.2.

This is the error I get from running catkin_make

```
  Could not find a configuration file for package "PCL" that is compatible
  with requested version "1.7.2".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    /usr/share/pcl-1.7/PCLConfig.cmake, version: 1.7.1
```

CMakeList file from my testPCD project dir is as follows ,removed some things so as not too bulky for listing here

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(testPCD)


find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  pcl_ros
  )
  

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
find_package(PCL 1.7.2 REQUIRED)

catkin_package(
  DEPENDS boost
  LIBRARIES
  CATKIN_DEPENDS
  pcl_ros
  )


###########
## Build ##
###########

 include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
 add_executable(testPCD src/testPCD.cpp)

 target_link_libraries(testPCD ${catkin_LIBRARIES}  ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
 add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207456/pcl-1.72-installation-question/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2015-04-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-04-22**:
If you change the version of PCL you will need to compile everything that depends on it from source. Please edit your question to show us how to everything you're doing so we can try to reproduce your problem.

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2015-04-22**:
updated question hopefully this is enough info...thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had made an error in installation effectively failing to run install which I am correcting and hopefully that will move me forward. Thanks for reviewing my question.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2015-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0